# How can you debug / track down problems in Fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I made an error when using a ViewHelper with an unsupported argument and *my Fluid Partial wasn't rendered at all*.

How can I debug / track down problems like these? Usually I would expect an exception to be thrown. I enabled debug preset and there is nothing in the sys_log, no error message is displayed.

Is there some setting I can use to cause error messages to be created or more information to get logged?

## Reproduce

Use Fluid ViewHelper with unsupported argument (here, *name* is not a supported argument):

```xml
<f:uri.external name="something" uri="https://typo3.org">f.uri.external</f:uri.external>
```

## Result

The Fluid Partial is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 1):

most of the time I'm using to check do I even get wanted values before:

```
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
```

or

```
<f:debug>{variable}</f:debug>
```

Comment: Yes, I also found <f:debug helpful. But it this case I had errors in my Fluid (using wrong arguments). The variables were fine.